# How do I secure postgres Username and password in Docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

My docker-compose file is

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.18-alpine3.14
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER : admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD : Pass@4321
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

Here user name and password is plain text. How can I secure my credentials in docker-compose.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than hardcoding your username and password in your `docker-compose.yaml`, one option is to replace them with variables, like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.18-alpine3.14
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER : $POSTGRES_USER
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD : $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

And then set them in your [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/):

```
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Pass@4321
```

When you `docker-compose up` your application, `docker-compose` will substitute the appropriate values.